# Example / Demo application using Carrierwave and ffmpeg gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, carrierwave

I've seen a lot of good example applications using the carrierwave gem for image uploading. I've not seen any for video uploading.

Can anyone share an example / demo Rails application using carrierwave and the ffmpeg gem (streemio-ffmpeg) or another video processing gem?

Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here, I would still really like to see some examples if anyone else cares to contribute. In the mean time there's these two:

https://github.com/zencoder/dreamlive (by Zencoder guys, a heroku app)

http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/video-encoding-with-uploadify-carrierwave-and-zencoder (uses uploadify [flash - argh...] but still useful overall. Found a couple of things have had to be changed as time has gone by but a lot of info is in there.)

Both are quite useful but not ideal. They use Zencoder which is not a video processing gem - it's just helps with the Zencoder API. Zencoder is a paid-for product by the people behind rVideo, one of the more comprehensive gems I noticed when on my ffmpeg hunt.

In then end I've decided that the cost of Zencoder is inconvenient but not as inconvenient as my server going down etc if I were to badly integrate my own in house video processing. I'm accepting this answer but it's not the best.